# Does the Game Boy version of Tetris have any crashing problems like the NES version?

Tags: nes, nintendo, game-boy

Apparently history has been made when a skilled gamer [manually crashed the NES Tetris at 1511 lines](https://arstechnica.com/gaming/2024/01/someone-has-finally-beaten-nes-tetris/)

> With rolling pushing NES Tetris games way longer than the original developers ever imagined it could go, players started noticing the game behaving unexpectedly. The oddities begin at Level 138, where a byte-overflow error causes the game to start reading unintended areas of memory as color palette data (as explained in more detail by HydrantDude here).

This is due to [how the NES calculates the score](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BpEcjdr_YDo) (TL;DR it's still adding to the score past the visual 999,999)

Does the Game Boy version suffer from any similar glitches?

Comment: Although it was a long time ago, I distinctly remember beating Tetris on my friend's GameBoy back in the early 1990s at the max difficulty level. I don't recall if there were other modes of play but my reward was that I got to see a nice animation of a space shuttle taking off. Or maybe it was a Buran. :)